# Azure Machine Learning Out of Memory Exception

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a simple experiment that points to a csv file for the data that I want to check.  The CSV file is 70MB (about 800,000 lines).  The Experiment contains only the following tasks:
1.  Get Data
2.  Select Columns (removes 3 columns from the data)
3.  Clean Missing Data (put in 0 values for missing data values)
4.  Split Data (75% / 25%)
5.  Linear Regression Algorithm
6.  Train Model
7.  Score Model

When I run this the Train Model gets and out of memory exception.  I'm currently only using the Free version, but I looked at the limits to this and it doesn't seem like that is what is limiting it.

The Train Model step runs for about 10 seconds before it errors out.  All of the previous steps took less than 1 minute to run.

Why am I getting this Out of memory exception.

Error Log
Record Starts at UTC 04/27/2017 13:17:40:

```
Run the job:"/dll "Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca;Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll.TrainGenericModel;Run" /Output0 "..\..\Trained model\Trained model.ilearner" /learner "..\..\Untrained model\Untrained model.ilearner" /trainingData "..\..\Dataset\Dataset.dataset" /labelColumnIndexOrName "%7B%22isFilter%22%3Atrue%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22ruleType%22%3A%22ColumnNames%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%22TotalInvoicedOrders%22%5D%2C%22exclude%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%2C%22ui%22%3A%7B%22withRules%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"  /ContextFile "..\..\_context\ContextFile.txt""
[Start] Program::Main
[Start]     DataLabModuleDescriptionParser::ParseModuleDescriptionString
[Stop]     DataLabModuleDescriptionParser::ParseModuleDescriptionString. Duration = 00:00:00.0041511
[Start]     DllModuleMethod::DllModuleMethod
[Stop]     DllModuleMethod::DllModuleMethod. Duration = 00:00:00.0000326
[Start]     DllModuleMethod::Execute
[Start]         DataLabModuleBinder::BindModuleMethod
[Verbose]             moduleMethodDescription Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca;Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll.TrainGenericModel;Run
[Verbose]             assemblyFullName Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca
[Start]             DataLabModuleBinder::LoadModuleAssembly
[Verbose]                 Loaded moduleAssembly Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca
[Stop]             DataLabModuleBinder::LoadModuleAssembly. Duration = 00:00:00.0092214
[Verbose]             moduleTypeName Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll.TrainGenericModel
[Verbose]             moduleMethodName Run
[Information]             Module FriendlyName : Train Model
[Information]             Module Release Status : Release
[Stop]         DataLabModuleBinder::BindModuleMethod. Duration = 00:00:00.0121124
[Start]         ParameterArgumentBinder::InitializeParameterValues
[Verbose]             parameterInfos count = 3
[Verbose]             parameterInfos[0] name = learner , type = Microsoft.Analytics.MachineLearning.ILearner
[Start]             CustomSerializationHandler::HandleArgumentString
[Start]                 DotNetSerializationHandler::HandleArgumentString
[Stop]                 DotNetSerializationHandler::HandleArgumentString. Duration = 00:00:00.0085176
[Stop]             CustomSerializationHandler::HandleArgumentString. Duration = 00:00:00.0114152
[Verbose]             parameterInfos[1] name = trainingData , type = Microsoft.Numerics.Data.Local.DataTable
[Start]             DataTableDatasetHandler::HandleArgumentString
[Stop]             DataTableDatasetHandler::HandleArgumentString. Duration = 00:00:02.8392062
[Verbose]             parameterInfos[2] name = labelColumnIndexOrName , type = Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.Common.Dll.ColumnSelection
[Stop]         ParameterArgumentBinder::InitializeParameterValues. Duration = 00:00:03.1559096
[Verbose]         Begin invoking method Run ... 
[ModuleOutput] LearnerDetails
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] {
[ModuleOutput]  "InputName":Untrained model
[ModuleOutput]  "LearnerKind":Microsoft.Analytics.MachineLearning.Local.BatchLinearRegressor
[ModuleOutput] }
[ModuleOutput] InputDataStructure
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] {
[ModuleOutput]  "InputName":Dataset
[ModuleOutput]  "Rows":621312
[ModuleOutput]  "Cols":16
[ModuleOutput]  "ColumnTypes":System.String,12,System.Int32,4
[ModuleOutput] }
[Stop]     DllModuleMethod::Execute. Duration = 00:00:06.7340783
[Critical]     Error: Error 0138: Memory has been exhausted, unable to complete running of module.
[Critical]     {"InputParameters":{"DataTable":[{"Rows":621312,"Columns":16,"estimatedSize":364380160,"ColumnTypes":{"System.String":12,"System.Int32":4},"IsComplete":true,"Statistics":{"0":[36,0],"1":[3,0],"2":[8,0],"3":[6.3737912675113311,6.0,0.0,12.0,3.6860947075263715,13.0,0.0],"4":[608.87559390451179,312.0,0.0,2057.0,629.92222860055733,210.0,0.0],"5":[63210657.808690317,87803073.0,0.0,99429245.0,40023846.6134889,2314.0,0.0],"6":[11.006466960238978,8.0,0.0,35.0,8.3750399881698172,25.0,0.0],"7":[15630,0],"8":[34078,0],"9":[6912,0],"10":[7132,0],"11":[12459,0],"12":[17,0],"13":[2693,0],"14":[4481,0],"15":[4481,0]}}],"Learner":[{"LearnerKind":"learner","LearnerSettings":{"name":"BatchLinearRegressor","isTrained":false,"settings":[["Bias","True"],["Regularization","0.001"],["AllowUnknownLevels","True"],["RandomNumberSeed",""]],"weights":[]}}],"Generic":{"labelColumnIndexOrName":"{\"isFilter\":true,\"rules\":[{\"ruleType\":\"ColumnNames\",\"columns\":[\"TotalInvoicedOrders\"],\"exclude\":false}],\"ui\":{\"withRules\":true}}"}},"OutputParameters":[],"ModuleType":"Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll","ModuleVersion":" Version=6.0.0.0","AdditionalModuleInfo":"Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca;Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.TrainGenericModel.Dll.TrainGenericModel;Run","Errors":"Microsoft.Analytics.Exceptions.ErrorMapping+ModuleException: Error 0138: Memory has been exhausted, unable to complete running of module.","Warnings":[],"Duration":"00:00:06.7274218"}
Module finished after a runtime of 00:00:07.2184726 with exit code -2
Module failed due to negative exit code of -2

Record Ends at UTC 04/27/2017 13:17:48.
```

Comment: Without the actual code, or stack trace of errors, its very hard to say

Comment: There is no code it is just the steps in the azureml studio that I listed and there is no stack trace unless somebody can tell me a way to get the stack trace.

Comment: I don't know why you give it a -1.  If you tell what other information I can provide you I will be more then happy to provide it.